# How to access Content Provider in NativeScript + Angular

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I need share offline data between 2 apps(NativeScript) and use the same database, I read that I can set a custom Content Provider and consume on another app. But don't know how to do this, I can't access the same methods that Native Java code can. 
Anyone knows how can I achieve that ?

Comment: There is nothing specific you have to do for Angular, please refer the [Java to JS](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js) docs, it covers everything you need for marshalling any Java code into JS. You can just get the current context of your application using `application.android.context`, using `getContentResolver()` on context will return [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html), I hope rest should be easy if you refer the official android docs / examples.

Comment: I don't have knowledge in Native Android, is a bit hard to know access the api directly ... I can not find any tutorials, docs about this subject...

Comment: I have already linked the marshalling docs in the above comment.It may not be possible to showcase every Android API in JavaScript but its a generic documentation shows you how you would access any native api.